# Retrieve values from NSMutableArray with addObjectsFromArray

Tags: ios6, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

BookmarksPlist is an NSMutableArray which was stored in the Plist file as a Dictionary. The following code...

```
bookmarks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSLog(@"BOOKMARKPLIST ----==== %@", BookmarksPlist);
[bookmarks addObjectsFromArray:BookmarksPlist];
NSLog(@"BOOKMARK ----==== %@", bookmarks);
```

...produces:

```
2012-11-27 11:34:33.592 BOOKMARKPLIST ----==== {
    01Otabkey14tabkey1 = "Genesis 14";
    01Otabkey8tabkey1 = "Genesis 8";
    01Otabkey9tabkey1 = "Genesis 9";
}
2012-11-27 11:34:33.592 *** -[NSMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:]: array argument is not an NSArray
2012-11-27 11:34:33.593 BOOKMARK ----==== (
    01Otabkey8tabkey1,
    01Otabkey9tabkey1,
    01Otabkey14tabkey1
)
```

So the question is how do I get the bookmarks array to take the values of the BookmarksPlist array and not the keys? So that it will look like this:

```
2012-11-27 11:34:33.593 BOOKMARK ----==== (
    "Genesis 14",
    "Genesis 8",
    "Genesis 9"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BookmarksPlist` is probably a dictionary. You can get the keys from a dictionary with `allKeys` and the values with `allValues`.